# Local fields : $K$ dense in $K_{\frak p}$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

someone can give me a reference where I can find the following result :

Let $K$ be a number field and let $\frak p$ be a place of $K$ then $K$ dense in $K_{\frak p}.$

thanks.

Comment: I don’t think you need a reference. Any metric space (or uniform space, for that matter) is dense in its completion. You can prove that directly from the definitions.

Comment: @Lubin thank you, I will try .

Comment: FYI, the proposition $4$ in section $3$, chapter $V$ of [**Basic Number Theory** by *André Weil*](http://www.amazon.com/Basic-Number-Theory-Classics-Mathematics/dp/3540586555) alludes to this; in effect, it proves this for lattices over an algebraic number-field.

Comment: @awllower  thank you,

Comment: NP, but notice that this is indeed not so dependent upon the structures of number-fields, as said Lubin.